# Prepositional phrase "at him"

Tags: prepositional-phrases

In this sentence:

> When he walked into the room, everyone stared at him.

"into the room" is a prepositional phrase but is "at him" also a prepositional phrase?

Comment: Yes, I assume so, as it's the object of "stared".  Could you explain why you want to know?  Is this related to some other grammar that you find confusing?

Comment: Yes, but calling it that hides the fact that the two phrases have significantly different functions. The verb is "stare at" - what they are staring at is an essential part of the meaning; whereas you can walk into, out of, along, or nowhere in particular: "into the room" is an optional extra. Modern grammatical theories regard "at him" as a complement, object, or argument of "stare" (depending on which precise theory), whereas "into the room" is only an "adjunct".

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Sentences can have multiple prepositional phrases, even in the same clause.

"When he walk" when he walked where? - "into the room"

"everyone stared" everyone stared where? - "at him".